# Unit test method with postdelayed

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, postdelayed

I have a method that makes an API Call after 1 sec. I use Handler.postdelayed to implement this. 
Now I am trying to verify if the API call is being made with a unit test.

```
@Mock
private PlanRepository planRepository;

@Mock
private CreatePlanContract.View view;

private CreatePlanContract.Presenter presenter;
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<ListResponseCallback<IntersectingList>> listCaptor;
....

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    presenter = new CreatePlanPresenter(resourceProvider, sessionContext, planRepository);
    presenter.start();
    presenter.setView(view);
    ...
}

@Test
public void testOnCameraIdleGetListEnabled(){
    presenter.onCameraIdle(true);

    verify(planRepository,times(1))
            .getList(listCaptor.capture());
}
```

This is the method in presenter that I want to test:

```
class PlanPresenter implements PlanContract.Presenter{
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mRunnable = this::fetchList;
    private WeakReference<CreatePlanContract.View> createPlanView;

    private ListResponseCallback<IntersectingList> listListener = new ListResponseCallback<Intersectinglist>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<IntersectingList> list) {
            Log.d(TAG, "callback: success resp came");
            if(createPlanView.get() != null)
                createPlanView.get().renderList(list);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i, @NonNull String s, @NonNull APIResponseBody apiResponseBody, @Nullable Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "callback: error resp came Auth");
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void start() {
        //some initilizations
    }

    @Override
    public void setView(@NonNull CreatePlanContract.View view) {
        this.createPlanView = new WeakReference<>(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle(){
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
    }

    private void fetchList(){
        //this the method to be verified
        planRepository.getList(listListener);
    }
}
```

But since the api call is being made after 1 sec, the test is failing.

What I have tried:
I tried following this [link](https://fernandocejas.com/2014/04/08/unit-testing-asynchronous-methods-with-mockito/) and use doAnswer() but I was unsuccessful.
I thought of using thread.sleep() which seems like an awful approach for this problem(also read that its a bad approach)

PS: I am a noob to testing.
I am using JUnit 4 and mockito

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line, before calling the method from the presenter class

`given(presenter.handler.postDelayed(any(Runnable.class), anyLong())).willReturn(true);`

As an example

```
given(presenter.handler.postDelayed(any(Runnable.class), anyLong())).willReturn(true);
presenter.doSomething();
```

Comment: I am not able to access the handler like this. It's a object in my presenter class

Comment: please share your presenter class

Comment: I added more details to presenter class

Comment: `private Handler mHandler = new Handler();` make this public, you will be able to access it.

Comment: I did try that but I m only able to access the methods that i override from the presenter contract interface

Comment: I also tried casting it like this given((CreatePlanPresenter)presenter)